# phone call Button

Tags: rules

I am a newbies in Drupal, currently I use Drupal 7.

I want to add one button into content type, to make the phone call when user click on this button.

I use module Button Field + Rule, but I don't know how to Rule create action like the link

```
<a href="tel:1-847-555-5555">1-847-555-5555</a>
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: You don’t need modules for this - it’s just basic HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the desired functionality is achievable via Button Field + Rules.
What you need is to create a plain text field to store the phone number, then you need to override the field template in your theme to output it as a link.
For example, if you field name is `telephone_link`, then you should create a file `field--telephone_link.tpl.php` under the folder `YOUR_THEME/templates/field` with the following content:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
      <a href="tel:<?php print $item['#markup'];?>" class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank @Ismail Cherri, it is really useful for me, thank you so much.